# How much duplication is permissible in letters of recommendation?

Tags: recommendation-letter, copyright

Anybody has idea, how much copying is allowed in a recommendation letter and whether they really run a copying test on the letters of recommendation?

Comment: I would *expect* that if the top 10% of the professor's students applied to grad school then he would say "this student is in the top 10% of my students" in all of them...

Comment: I am not even sure a letter of recommendation can be plagiarized, merely copied.

Comment: I edited the title from enthusiastic student's version. S/he used the phrase "copyright" which isn't applicable. No one is disputing the copyright status of letters so it's a moot point. The question is whether letter writers should write letter de novo, whether they should recycle text, or whether they should 'borrow' text (from the student or from posted letters of recommendation).

Comment: Copying WHAT and FROM WHERE? Nobody expects you to retype the name of the applicant and the exact formulation of his theorems (or whatever) or, God forbid, try to be "inventive" about the way you present them. The letter of recommendation consists of two parts: the publicly available information about the candidate (where the closer you are to how it is presented in CV, publication list, etc., the better) and your own opinion about it (where any construct starting with "copying" will be an oxymoron by definition).

Comment: As to "running a copying test on letters of recommendation", all I can say is that the set of people who lost all touch with common sense and reality after reading our written "academic honesty policies" in our class syllabi is certainly non-empty... In short, "No". In long: "What a novel and fascinating idea!"

Answer (score 26):

While our university occasionally submits statements of purpose, research statements, and writing samples through plagiarism detectors (and gives the admissions committee the results), I have never seen this done to letters of recommendation.

There are just very limited ways of saying nice things about students. I use the same variation of an opening for all my letters, with only minor changes in intensity (I am very/slightly/marginally pleased to write this letter of recommendation) and close with the same sentence on all of them.

I wouldn't worry.

---

Addendum given the changes to the the original question: I don't know if people have seen the output of plagiarism detectors but they don't provide  a simple YES/NO answer. Instead, they provide a statistical quantification of how much unquoted text *might* be drawn from other sources (e.g., 3-5% of the text appears duplicative). Each report is several pages long with parts of the student text highlighted and possible prior sources highlighted.

The reports are quite "noisy" with many false positives -- notably in one case that I remember, highlighting text in the *bibliography* because the citations matched citations in other bibliographies. [facepalm]

Running LORs through plagiarism detectors would serve no useful evaluative purpose in terms of how the admissions committee views the *candidate*.

Comment: Oh man, I would be absolutely crushed if someone gave me a letter that began with, "I am marginally pleased to write this letter..."

Comment: That's why you always ask your professors if they will write you a *strong* letter of recommendation.

Comment: @Asad:  That is why I decline, politely, I hope, to write letters for students when I cannot write "recommend" or "strongly recommend."  I say, "You should ask professors in whose classes you did better than you did in mine."

Answer (score 16):

There isn't much creativity involved in most recommendation letters. And frankly, that doesn't matter. The important thing to a school or employer is that the individual who signed the letter believes it accurately describes you.

Yes, it would be nice if every letter was rewritten completely de novo. It isn't very surprising when it doesn't happen that way.

Don't worry about it. The worst that will happen is that they'll contact the recommender, he'll say you're a good candidate, and that'll be the end of it.

Comment: -1: It's important to me that recommendation letters are written by the ones who sign them.  (This is my opinion as someone who has had a lot of involvement with graduate admissions over the years, at UGA.  If you are involved in graduate admissions elsewhere and make a practice of not caring about this, I would be very interested to know.)  On the other hand, I don't agree with "[I]t would be nice if every letter was rewritten completely de novo".  This is really not required.  But taking too much of someone else's writing and claiming it as your own is never okay in an academic environment.

Comment: @petelclark: this isn't  an academic document; it's a near-form-letter endorsement, modified for the particular case. It may be the same letter, essentially,that he uses for all similar references.  I honestly see no harm here other than the risk that the admissions comittee may get bored if they see: the same text too many ti mes. Gods know that the students are always looking for boilerplate they can model their applications on; why isn't this equally legit?

Comment: Form letter endorsements for PhD programs make for poor recommendation letters, of the sort that significantly hurt the student's chances.  And yes, this is a kind of academic document.  May I ask again what admissions experience you have?

Comment: And in any case, that's something you should debate w/ the recommender,rather than faulting the applicant on,  if you care at all about fairness.

Comment: "[I]f you care at all about fairness." Of course I care about fairness.  What is it that you are suggesting?

Comment: Also, if you read my answer, you'll notice that I said that using boiler-plate language as part of a recommendation letter is okay.  However, in order to be a good letter thee needs to be something there beyond the boiler-plate.  If the distinctive part is stolen from someone else without attribution, that is problematic.  And again, what I'm disagreeing with is "The important thing to a school or employer is that the individual who signed the letter believes it accurately describes you." I am (a representative of) the school, so I am pointing out that it doesn't work that way.

Comment: Remember, the whole letter wasn't borrowed, just a portion thereof. We haven't seen the letter, we don't know, we don't even know whether it would in fact be recognized as reused language rather than just somewhat hackneyed.... We agree that we disagree. And, again, would you blame the kid for the fact that the letter wasn't 100% original? If so that isn't fair to him; if not your objections are entirely (pardon the pun) academic. A difference which makes no difference is no difference.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking that my answer doesn't already address.  I already said that in this case the OP very probably has nothing to worry about.  However, your answer makes a broader assertion about what schools find important.  I am telling you, as a graduate admissions representative, that this is not the case.  When you say you disagree, what do you mean?  That in your experience PhD admissions are handled differently?  If people followed your advice and, for instance, wrote their own letters, it would almost certainly hurt their applications.  That is a real risk.

Comment: You misread me badly. I never suggested people write  letters recommending themselves. I'm leaving it there.

Comment: You wrote: "The important thing to a school or employer is that the individual who signed the letter believes it accurately describes you."  The use of the word "signed" implies that it is not important to those who process admissions who wrote the letter so long as the signer believes it is an accurate description of the candidate.  Since I and the vast majority of other faculty doing graduate admissions I know vehemently disagree with that, I am commenting.  If that is not your intended meaning, perhaps you should edit your answer.  I ask  once again: how do you know what we find important?

Comment: We agree that we disagree.  Stet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19731/discussion-between-keshlam-and-pete-l-clark). Or not. (I was hoping the move-to-chat would actually move some of this chain to chat and clean up; apparently not. Oh well.)

Comment: I find it fascinating that the admissions process would actually care if the letter was actually written by the endorser, rather than the fact that it was signed by the endorser.  I guess its time to write a pseudo-random recommendation generator macro, and quite frankly @PeteL.Clark, writing your own letter is apparently the only way to get a fair review from someone like you.

Comment: @Jim B: I have explained elsewhere on this site why a student writing their own recommendation letter for a PhD program would be a very poor decision.  I take issues of fairness very seriously, and the position that I am taking here is identical to that of the vast majority of my colleagues at American universities.  What is your experience with PhD admissions that leads you to give such divergent advice?

Comment: I do not believe anything unfair has been suggested here except an arguably unreasonable  demand for complete originality in recommendation letters ... which is an issue to take up with recommenders, not  one the student should be judged upon. I agree that an exceptionally specific recc will stand out and carry additional weight, of course; that's entirely appropriate. But if the recc  simply says excellent candidate for program X, and comes from someone with authority in that area, how much do you reallly want to downgrade the application... unless it's english dept, maybe.

Comment: @keshlam: I don't see that anyone here has suggested (let alone demanded) "complete originality in recommendation letters".  If you have followup questions about the nature and meaning of academic recommendation letters, feel free to ask.  Most of the people who write these letters understand the culture and requirements of the form.  Those who don't write letters that are less effective than they could be or than they are intended to be.  I hope you now see why it is not helpful to make assumptions about what a good letter is without having familiarity with the graduate admissions process.

Comment: Assuming that you are in fact interested in the truth, I'll start you out with this: an overly short or completely generic letter is often intended as -- and even more often read as -- code for a lack of enthusiasm about the student.  What (based on past direct experience on this site) many outsiders don't seem to realize is that faculty have a direct stake in placing their students in the best possible programs: doing so is part of our job.  So even really famous, busy people write enough to give their students their best chance....if they think the students deserve to be there.

Answer (score 12):

> Anybody has any idea, how much plagiarism is allowed in a recommendation letter and whether they really run a plagiarism test on the letters of recommendation?

I have read literally thousands of academic recommendation letters, and I have never run one through plagiarism detection software.  I don't understand why you did that *after* the letter was submitted: what were you hoping to gain?

You also sound slightly naive about how "plagiarism detection software" works.  Such software does not directly detect plagiarism; it only makes a more or less compelling case for it according to the degree of similarity.  The letter is a highly structured, ritualized writing style.  Having 10% of a letter be the same as some other letter is not itself problematic, and it certainly need not imply "10% plagiarized".

A recommendation letter is not an academic paper, and most people who write many (graduate school) recommendation letters keep a basic template and fill in information accordingly.  Therefore a lot of recommendation letters are going to be a lot more than 10% alike without there being anything problematic.  This is another reason why putting a graduate recommendation letter through a plagiarism detector is not a very plausible thing to do.

In summary: I think it is overwhelmingly unlikely that anyone except you will know what percentage of this letter the plagiarism software reported as copied.  I doubt you'll have a problem.

On the other hand, I am not quite willing to say that including an entire paragraph in a letter that one found on the internet is a good practice.  It depends a lot on what the paragraph is.  If the language in that paragraph is boiler-plate or standard, then I certainly don't care.  (In particular, I hope you would have told us if the copied paragraph was the very last one, e.g. something like "In summary, Ms. X is a very strong candidate and deserves the highest consideration.  Please do not hesitate to contact me if you require further information.") However, if the paragraph contains distinctive, poetic or especially clever language and your writer lifted it from the internet because he liked someone else's clever language better than his own: well, it has nothing to do with *you*, but I don't think is a good practice, and it doesn't fill me with confidence about his writing skills or professional ethics.

Answer (score 5):

Almost every prof I know uses a template for recommendation letters, and adds a paragraph or two specific to the student.  I'm not surprised a about the reuse of a paragraph and similar wording.

Remember, the purpose of a letter of recommendation is to make the case that you are a good student, and will be a dedicated, ethical researcher, not to introduce new research or new ideas.  A letter of recommendation would likely not pass several requirements of publish, professional research as it does not present a novel idea, nor does it have external references.

A recommendation letter is a vote of confidence in the individual.  Its difficult to see how similar content between letters would hurt either the recommend-er or the recommend-ee, so long as the recommendation accurately reflects the opinion of the recommend-er.

Comment: One person who could be harmed by a plagiarized recommendation letter is the person whose distinctive language and/or ideas the plagiarist stole.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark is right - and the reputation of the plagiarist could also be severely harmed, I would think.

Comment: Come to think of it, it could also do harm to the person being recommended, depending on the amount of content that's copied.

Comment: While all the comments would be true about plagiarism, most recommendation letters (in my experience) don't meet other requirements of professional writing as they do not usually have any novel idea or new research presented.  Its the opinion of a current researcher usually without references, which would be unpublishable anyway.

Comment: The concept of plagiarism doesn't just apply to academic papers.  The practice of copying others' distinctive language or ideas without attribution is viewed as unethical by (e.g.) academics in whatever context.  As I (and others) have said, whether the duplicated paragraph is problematic depends on what it is.  We have already said that this hunting expedition is poorly motivated, and the paragraph would have to be something truly artful and distinctive for it to be even worth shaking a finger at.  But, for instance, lifting a whole paragraph from someone else's short story would be bad.

Comment: Consider this example.  You and a few friends are planning a trip, and one of your friends suggest inviting someone you don't know.  You want to make sure this person you don't know will not detract from the trip, so you politely ask about this new person.  The person who suggested it vouches for his "coolness", then a few other friends add in they've meet him, and say he's cool.  In this example, everyone who knows him will probably say "he seems cool," followed by a brief explanation.

Answer (score 3):

This seems like a strange question to me, because if I were a new-ish prof asked to write a letter of recommendation, the very first thing I would do would be to type "letter of recommendation template" into Google (12.9 million hits), and use the first one that seemed to fit.  Since I think I am not much lazier than the average new prof (and in STEM, have the advantage of being a native English speaker), I'd expect the majority of letters to be created the same way.

Answer (score 2):

I am surprised that nobody has mentioned the possibility that the supposed "plagiarist" recommender used his/her own text, which was also coincidentally found online.

While a cut-and-pasted paragraph of 50 words strongly suggests copying of some kind, it is not necessarily the case that the 50 words were plagiarism (i.e. usage of another person's text without attribution).

It could very likely be the case that the recommender posted up one of his/her old recommendation letters online, and it got picked up as a template text by the anti-plagiarism software, which then detected the similarity. I would not at all find it surprising that my recommender(s) were reusing parts of their old recommendation letters, as they clearly have much better things to do with their time than write a completely new recommendation letter for each application.

In fact, it could even be the case that your recommender did not even post his/her letter online. Assuming your recommender has also forwarded their recommendation letter to his/her past students, it is not a stretch to consider that the student could have posted that letter online.

With the limited information, I find it rather uncalled for to immediately jump to the conclusion that your recommender has committed plagiarism.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the title isn't quite asking the same question as the question body.

The direct answer to "Is there any copyright on letters of recommendation?" is that it depends on the country you're in (because copyright law differs from one country to another), but if you're in the UK or the USA then copyright automatically attaches to the creation of an original written work such as a letter. No need to register the copyright or declare it. Letters of recommendation are not exempt by virtue of their subject matter.

> copyright in the United States automatically attaches upon the creation of an original work of authorship

[WP: Copyright law of the United States](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_law_of_the_United_States#Registration_procedure)

So the general answer is: Yes, letters (whatever the topic) do fall under copyright law.

> "how much copying is allowed in a recommendation letter"?

Copying from oneself is fine (so long as one still owns the copyright in the work being copied). Copying from someone else is not, unless they've given you permission to do so.